# How to implement Contact connection (mimetype) to launch my application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, mime-types, android-contacts

I need some help with this scenario fro my application: When the user is going to a specific contact and click that link icon (like What's up ), the application (eq. WhatsUp) is opened with that contact id.

[image: Here you can see the links icons]

So far what I did: 
- I succeed to add my custom data for a specific contact . I have my app icon and the mimedata custom data with that contact. The mimetype that I defined within the contact data is:    **"vnd.android.cursor.item/com.sunny.contacts.Account"**

Now on manifest I configured main activity the following:

```
    <activity
       android:name=".ActivityMain"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />     
        </intent-filter>    
        <intent-filter>         
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.sunny.contacts.Account"/>      
        </intent-filter>    
   </activity>
```

On **ActivityMain::OnCreate** I'm reading the Intent data but unfortunately the application is not opened and I have no idea what is wrong.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Can you share your code to update contacts to add your custom mime type?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.sunny.contacts.Account"/>`
use this `<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.sunny.contacts.profile"/>`

which you defined in xml

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.sunny.contacts.profile"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:detailSocialSummary="true" />
</ContactsSource>
```

Comment: can anyone suggest code how to get contact data from intent in ViewActivity.

Comment: are you looking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327416/pick-contact-directly-from-contact-picker-intent