# Pick contact directly from contact picker intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-implicit-intent, contactpicker

Hello I want to pick a contact from our default contact book intent.
I tried several ways to do it. Please find the code below. The problem with all those code is that they open one intermediate documents screen with few options there user has to select contact and than it opens contact book.

```
private void openContactIntent() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
     intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CONTACT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

I also tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

What I see as an intermediate screen is [image]

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);` It's working for me!

Comment: Is it related to any OS ? I am running code on Android N. And for me it not working. I have not added any permissions.

Comment: I am running Android N too!

Comment: And permissions ?

Comment: This is opening a side menu screen like attached screenshot in phone and not even showing contact inside it.

Comment: No permission needed! Paste your `targetSdkVersion`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131485/discussion-between-android-griezmann-and-hardik-trivedi).

Comment: I am able to solve the problem. There is some catch with the request code. I was using request code 10. The moment I use some odd number like 8500 it started working fine. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to insert contact into edittext using contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781618/trying-to-insert-contact-into-edittext-using-contact-picker)

Answer (score 20):

I also had the same problem. Finally, I got rid of intermediate picker screen using below code,

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

In `onActivityResult` get phone number as below

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
  Uri contactUri = data.getData();
  String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
  Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
      null, null, null);

  // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
    // Do something with the phone number
    ... 
  } 

  cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me except getContext needed to be replaced with a reference to the activity (this), otherwise I got a no instrumentation registered issue.

Comment: Works well but the result code is random for some reason, could be an Android 11 issue

Comment: For Android  11+, changes in AndroidManifest file like https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600033/1889825

Answer (score 14):

Try the below code to pick contact:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
```

You can fetch the required information in onActivityResult as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                  Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null;
        String name = null;

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);

       Log.e("Name and Contact number is",name+","+phoneNo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                break;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Failed", "Not able to pick contact");
    }
}
```

Comment: oH..!! It's great..!!

Comment: This actually still opens the file manager on some devices, better also add `intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);`

Comment: here what is RESULT_PICK_CONTACT . it is string or other variable ?

Comment: [@Ganesan J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11828164/ganesan-j) It's an `int`, have a look at [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) article

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to pick name, phone number from Contact in Kotlin

```
private fun pickEmergencyFromContacts() {
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    i.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
    startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val contactUri = data?.data ?: return
        val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
        val cursor = requireContext().contentResolver.query(contactUri, projection,
                null, null, null)

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            val number = cursor.getString(numberIndex)

            // do something with name and phone
        }
        cursor?.close()
    }
}

companion object {

    private const val SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER = 111    
    ...
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: This only gives 1 contact, is there a way to select multiple contacts in one go?

Answer (score 3):

**StarActivityForResult** is deprecated. So we can use below model in Kotlin.

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**Please implement run-time permission also. I haven't done in my code.**

**Below lines used to handle the result:**

```
    private val openContacts = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()) {

    val contactData: Uri = it
    val phone: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(contactData!!, null, null, null, null)
    if (phone!!.moveToFirst()) {
        val contactName: String = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))

        // To get number - runtime permission is mandatory.
        val id: String = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
        if (phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)).toInt() > 0) {
            val phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null)
            while (phones!!.moveToNext()) {
                val phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                Log.d("## Number", phoneNumber)
            }
            phones!!.close()
        }

        Log.d("## Contact Name", contactName)
    }

}
```

**To open the contacts:**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        openContacts.launch(null)
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to call the pending intents using the registerActivityForResult. I am stuck with a compile-time error where .launch() function is expecting a pending intent.

Comment: I didn't try with pending intent. Below link answer may help to you, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362525/start-pendingintent-for-result

Answer (score 2):

For Android 11+, need to add below code in AndroidManifest

```
......
</application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
     ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(it, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT1= 1;
 public void pickContact1 (View v)
      {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT1);
      }
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT1:
                    contactPicked1(data);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("SetupActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
        }
    }

 private void contactPicked1 (Intent data){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String phoneNo = null;
            String name = null;
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
            ed11.setText(name);
            ed12.setText(phoneNo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a nice to have implementation (in Kotlin) that I'll add here to help getting the contact info from the cursor.
You will also need to grant permissions and request runtime permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

```
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private fun getContactDataFrom(
        contentResolver: ContentResolver,
        contactUri: Uri
    ): ContactModel? {
        val projection = arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
        )

        try {
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null) ?: return null
            if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return null
            }

            val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
            val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
            val hasNumber = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))
            cursor.close()

            val email = getEmail(contentResolver, id)

            val phoneNumber = if (hasNumber > 0) {
                getPhoneNumber(contentResolver, id)
            } else {
                ""
            }
            return ContactModel(name, phoneNumber, email)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Contacts", "Could not get contact info.", e)
            return null
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private fun getPhoneNumber(contentResolver: ContentResolver, id: String?): String {
        var phoneNumber = ""

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?",
            arrayOf(id),
            null
        ) ?: return phoneNumber

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA))
        }

        cursor.close()
        return phoneNumber
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private fun getEmail(contentResolver: ContentResolver, id: String?): String {
        var email = ""

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            arrayOf(id),
            null
        ) ?: return email

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))
        }

        cursor.close()
        return email
    }
```

Trigger:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, PickLabelActivity::class.java)               
    startActivityForResult(intent, PickLabelActivity.REQ_CODE_PICK_LABEL)
```

Usage in onActivityResult should be something like:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == ConstantsHandler.INTENT_CODE_PICK_CONTACT) {
            val contactUri = data?.data ?: return
            val contactModel = getContactDataFrom(contentResolver, contactUri)

            inputName.setText(contactModel?.name)
            inputPhone.setText(contactModel?.phone)
            inputEmail.setText(contactModel?.email)
        }
    }
```

And that ContactModel is just a simple data class.

```
data class ContactModel(
    var name: String? = null,
    var phone: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null
) : Serializable
```